# IIS (10.0.17763.1) New Site Fails with 404 Errors

Tags: website, http-status-code-404, iis-10

I am hoping that someone may have the answer to this. I created a new site on IIS (full disclosure, I created the first one incorrectly and removed it, if that matters).

My IIS server has several hosted sites, all working fine, apart from the new one.

I am to start with trying to access a static file index.html

- The application pool is set as default, the same as the other sites.
- The Path credentials are set as an admin account; I get the two green
  ticks.
- I have even tried setting this website to one of the other
  website paths to test the file access and get the same 404 error! Weird.
- I have checked that the file I am accessing has the correct extension. There is nothing
  in the log file being generated for this site. Tried a custom path
  for a log and still nothing.
- With just the root address http://www.example.com/ I get the IIS default welcome page.
- I tried   renaming the default websites bindings to the new site name to try
  and use that directory. Same result, 404.
- Sites restarted. Server restarted.

I am totally at a loss and have googled silly.... any help greatly appreciated. Its a very odd error and I still wonder if its remembered something about the original site i created and deleted.

Comment: Find out the http sub-status in the http logs of the site, it is the number to the right of the `404`. Then look up the meaning of the sub-status.

Comment: Thank you. I found it, it was actually a DNS error and a missing binding diverting to a default site.

Comment: If you found the answer, you should post and accept it below or simply delete the question.

Comment: Hi, Sorry been meaning to come and update with the answer for a while. It was ultimately a silly mistake, but one that might help someone else. There was a DNS error but ultimately this resulted in IIS serving the default website, rather than one of the named sites. I would recommend putting a specific, single holding page on your default site, so if you get traffic to the default site, you can identify it rather than getting a 404.

Answer (score 0):

NO idea if this will help anyone but remember that Windows by default will hide extensions.  If you create a brand new server, and create a new IIS site, and create a test page in notepad, the test page will be saved as .txt file.  IIS won't read it.  And you won't know that because by default the extensions are hidden.  Newbie mistake but hard to catch.